# How to return an attribute if it's not empty or call method to populate attribute if it is empty

Tags: python

I have a class where one of the attributes is data I get from a web api. I don't need the attribute every time I use the class so I don't want to make the api call when it is instantiated, but I also don't want to make the call every time I access the attribute. How can I return the attribute if it is already populated, or call a method to populate the attribute if it isn't? If I try to assign the attribute to an empty list on instantiation I get an "cant' set attribute" error if I remove the attribute from the init method I get a "maximum recursion depth" error.

Option 1-

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, id, data=None):
        self.id = id
        self.data = [] if data is None else data

    @property
    def data(self):
        if self.data:
            return self.data
        else:
            self._get_data_from_api()
            return self.data
     def _get_data_from_api(self):
        return requests.get(url, headers).json()
```

Option 2-

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    @property
    def data(self):
        if self.data:
            return self.data
        else:
            self._get_data_from_api()
            return self.data

        def _get_data_from_api(self):
            return requests.get(url, headers).json()
```

Comment: Your indentation is broken; you have a lot of methods nested inside other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cache the API response in an instance attribute that is initialized as `None` so that the `data` property method would only retrieve data from the API if the caching attribute is `None`:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self._data = None

    @property
    def data(self):
        if self._data is None:
            self._data = self._get_data_from_api()
        return self._data

    def _get_data_from_api(self):
        return requests.get(url, headers).json()
```

Comment: I think I could also use an empty list instead of a None value, but my mistake was not including the leading underscore in the init method to differentiate it from the property method. I mean, one of my mistakes. Thanks